# Cannot find module 'spawn-sync' Appcelerator studio

Tags: appcelerator

I tried to create new Mobile app project on Appcelerator studio but unsuccessfully. The detail error is *Cannot find module 'spawn-sync'*. Did I missed anything. Please see the log and give me some advice.

```
[2016/12/23 10:16:24] Thanh Long: The following data will be sent:

------
STATUS
------
pluginId            com.appcelerator.titanium.360.core
pluginVersion       1.1.0.1470644237
code                0
severity            4
message             (Build 4.8.1.201612050850) [ERROR]  An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot find module 'spawn-sync'
fingerprint         fecf93da
stacktrace          

Caused by: Exception:org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot find module 'spawn-sync'
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.callAPI(TitaniumUserManager.java:228)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.ThreeSixtyProject.doGetOrganization(ThreeSixtyProject.java:153)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.ThreeSixtyProject.getOrganization(ThreeSixtyProject.java:127)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium360.internal.ui.launch.OnDemandPlansLaunchValidator.preLaunchCheck(OnDemandPlansLaunchValidator.java:57)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.AbstractPackagingLaunchShortcut.preLaunchCheck(AbstractPackagingLaunchShortcut.java:65)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.AbstractTitaniumLaunchShortcut.launch(AbstractTitaniumLaunchShortcut.java:54)
     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:431)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.LaunchAppToolbarContribution$4.mouseUp(LaunchAppToolbarContribution.java:490)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:220)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4042)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3669)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:126)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot find module 'spawn-sync'
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.handleResponse(TitaniumUserManager.java:277)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.callAPI(TitaniumUserManager.java:224)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.ThreeSixtyProject.doGetOrganization(ThreeSixtyProject.java:153)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.ThreeSixtyProject.getOrganization(ThreeSixtyProject.java:127)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium360.internal.ui.launch.OnDemandPlansLaunchValidator.preLaunchCheck(OnDemandPlansLaunchValidator.java:57)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.AbstractPackagingLaunchShortcut.preLaunchCheck(AbstractPackagingLaunchShortcut.java:65)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.AbstractTitaniumLaunchShortcut.launch(AbstractTitaniumLaunchShortcut.java:54)
     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:431)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.LaunchAppToolbarContribution$4.mouseUp(LaunchAppToolbarContribution.java:490)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:220)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4042)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3669)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:126)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

------
STATUS
------
pluginId            com.appcelerator.titanium.core
pluginVersion       3.1.2.1478890706
code                0
severity            4
message             An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot find module 'spawn-sync' [detached from CoreException of Status '(Build 4.8.1.201612050850) [ERROR]  An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot find module 'spawn-sync'' by Error Reporting]
fingerprint         a663234c
stacktrace
[2016/12/23 10:16:58] Thanh Long: Exception:org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot find module 'spawn-sync'
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.callAPI(TitaniumUserManager.java:228)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.ThreeSixtyProject.doGetOrganization(ThreeSixtyProject.java:153)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.ThreeSixtyProject.getOrganization(ThreeSixtyProject.java:127)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium360.internal.ui.launch.OnDemandPlansLaunchValidator.preLaunchCheck(OnDemandPlansLaunchValidator.java:57)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.AbstractPackagingLaunchShortcut.preLaunchCheck(AbstractPackagingLaunchShortcut.java:65)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.AbstractTitaniumLaunchShortcut.launch(AbstractTitaniumLaunchShortcut.java:54)
     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:431)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.LaunchAppToolbarContribution$4.mouseUp(LaunchAppToolbarContribution.java:490)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:220)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4042)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3669)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:126)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot find module 'spawn-sync'
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.handleResponse(TitaniumUserManager.java:277)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.callAPI(TitaniumUserManager.java:224)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.ThreeSixtyProject.doGetOrganization(ThreeSixtyProject.java:153)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.ThreeSixtyProject.getOrganization(ThreeSixtyProject.java:127)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium360.internal.ui.launch.OnDemandPlansLaunchValidator.preLaunchCheck(OnDemandPlansLaunchValidator.java:57)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.AbstractPackagingLaunchShortcut.preLaunchCheck(AbstractPackagingLaunchShortcut.java:65)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.AbstractTitaniumLaunchShortcut.launch(AbstractTitaniumLaunchShortcut.java:54)
     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:431)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.LaunchAppToolbarContribution$4.mouseUp(LaunchAppToolbarContribution.java:490)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:220)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4042)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3669)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
[2016/12/23 10:17:00] Thanh Long: at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:126)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Exception:org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot find module 'spawn-sync'
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.handleResponse(TitaniumUserManager.java:277)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.callAPI(TitaniumUserManager.java:224)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.ThreeSixtyProject.doGetOrganization(ThreeSixtyProject.java:153)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.ThreeSixtyProject.getOrganization(ThreeSixtyProject.java:127)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium360.internal.ui.launch.OnDemandPlansLaunchValidator.preLaunchCheck(OnDemandPlansLaunchValidator.java:57)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.AbstractPackagingLaunchShortcut.preLaunchCheck(AbstractPackagingLaunchShortcut.java:65)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.launching.AbstractTitaniumLaunchShortcut.launch(AbstractTitaniumLaunchShortcut.java:54)
     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:431)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.ui.LaunchAppToolbarContribution$4.mouseUp(LaunchAppToolbarContribution.java:490)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:220)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4042)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3669)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
     at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:126)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

------
STATUS
------
pluginId            com.appcelerator.titanium.core
pluginVersion       3.1.2.1478890706
code                0
severity            1
message             An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot find module 'spawn-sync' [detached from CoreException of Status 'An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot find module 'spawn-sync'' by Error Reporting]
fingerprint         00000000
stacktrace          


------
REPORT
------
name                trinh.thanh.long@nck.co.jp
email               anonymous
comment             
productVersion      4.8.1.201612050850
productName         Appcelerator Studio
javaRuntimeVersion  1.7.0_79-b15
osgiWs              cocoa
osgiOs              MacOSX
osgiOsVersion       10.12.2
osgiArch            x86_64
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, I ended up with the same trouble when I upgraded Appcelerator CLI to 6.2.3 in mac os. What I did is, I manually installed the node module spawn-sync for appcelerator. please note, it's not global installation.

ie; I went to the path `/Users/{username}/.appcelerator/install/6.2.3/package/`
then ran the command `npm install spawn-sync`

This solved my issue.

You may try the same by navigating to `/Users/{username}/.appcelerator/install/{cli-version}/package/`

Answer (score 1):

in my case I resolved the issue deleting configuration folder of Appcelerator Studio, in Mac OS is a hidden folder in the personal profile (~./appcelerator).
Best Regards.